# Miniconda installation gives "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"

Tags: installation, miniconda

I am trying to install Miniconda with the following code `bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3` but I receive the error below:

```
PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 649, in __init__
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 168, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 43, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[3517968] Failed to execute script 'entry_point' due to unhandled exception!
```

I need to mention that I do not have admin status on the server, and there is 702G of free space. I feel like the problem is caused by me not being admin.

Still, I would be very appreciated if you could tell me the problem and the solution.

Thank you very much in advance.